# top_n() not selecting n

Tags: r, dplyr, top-n

Aim: To plot the first 20 countries in descending order

Problem: When using the `top_n` function, it insists in selecting all and not just the top 20.

Here is my code:

```
#Omit missing values
na.omit(kiva_loans)%>%
  #Group by country label
  group_by(country_code)%>%
  dplyr::count(country_code, sort = TRUE)%>%
  top_n(20)%>%
   ggplot(aes(reorder(x=country_code,n),y=n))+
   geom_col(position="dodge",
            color = "black",
            fill="purple")+
   coord_flip()
```

After the `top_n(20)` line, the output is:

[image]

Which shows that it isn't cutting it off at 20. This is the horrid plot in turn:

[image]

Comment: it's probably because of the `group_by`, what if you `ungroup()` just before call `top_n`?

Comment: Thanks Riccardo! This was it!

Comment: If you want to select top N ordered values you can just use `head(N)`

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas, I just wanted to understand `dplyr` well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#Omit missing values
na.omit(kiva_loans)%>%
  #Group by country label
  group_by(country_code)%>%
  dplyr::count(country_code, sort = TRUE)%>%
  ungroup() %>% # add this to ungroup
  top_n(20)%>%
   ggplot(aes(reorder(x=country_code,n),y=n))+
   geom_col(position="dodge",
            color = "black",
            fill="purple")+
   coord_flip()
```

Just `ungroup()` before you call `top_n`

From `?top_n` you can read this:

> n number of rows to return. If x is grouped, this is the number of rows per group. Will include more than n rows if there are ties.